# Investigate whether the function is differentiated at the point (0,0).

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

> Investigate whether the function 
>   $$F(x,y)= \begin{cases}
> \frac{x^{3}}{x^{2}+y^{2}},  & (x,y) \neq (0,0)  \\
> 0, & (x,y) = (0,0)
> \end{cases}$$
>   is differentiated at the point (0,0).

---

My solution:

Consider polar form of a point 
$$x = r \cos(\alpha) $$
$$y = r \sin(\alpha)$$

We have $$\frac{r^{3}\cos(\alpha)}{r^{t}} = r\cos(\alpha)$$

When $r\mapsto 0$ then $r\cos(\alpha)) = 0$, because $|\cos{\alpha} | \leq 1$

Comment: Shouldn't the question be "Investigate if the function is differentiable at (0,0)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not differentiable at $(0,0)$. Note that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0)=1$ and that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(0,0)=0$ and that therefore *if* $f$ was differentiable at $(0,0)$, *then* we would have$$(\forall(a,b)\in\mathbb R^2):f'(0,0)(a,b)=a.$$But this is not true, since it would mean that$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{\bigl\lvert f(x,y)-f(0,0)-f'(0,0)(x,y)\bigr\rvert}{\bigl\lVert(x,y)\bigr\rVert}=0,$$which is equivalent to$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{\lvert xy^2\rvert}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}}=0.\tag1$$But, if $y=x$ and $x>0$, then$$\frac{\lvert xy^2\rvert}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}}=\frac{x^3}{2^{3/2}x^3}=2^{-3/2}$$and therefore $(1)$ doesn't hold.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Use that $$f(x,y)$$ is diferentiable at $(0,0)$ if and only if $$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}\frac{f(x,y)-f(0,0)-f_x(0,0)x-f_y(0,0)y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=0$$